# Microsoft Graph API - Search content over a sharepoint site

Tags: search, graph, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

We are creating a Sharepoint webpart that enable searching a Sharepoint site contents using Microsoft Graph Api. I am able to get the Lists and subsites
using graph Api, but not sure how to search any content at site level.
Looking for any pointers if this is even achievable.

Below are some of the API calls that work-

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenants/lists?select=id,name
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenants:/sites/sitename:/sites?search=subsitename
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenants:/sites/sitecollection:/lists

Answer (score 0):

here is an example filtering on a list items

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myThing.sharepoint.com,ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff,12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/lists/25dd5a71-69a9-44f8-b60f-ed16718eae54/items?expand=fields(select%3DTitle,ID,ContentType,myLookupID)&top=1000&filter=fields/ContentType eq 'My Page'`